# NSString to 64-bit integer conversion on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, 64-bit, nsstring, integer

I am struggling with very simple thing:
I receive some ids by http request as a string. I know they represent 64-bit integer id numbers.
How can I convert them to the 64-bit Integers (NSNumber or NSInteger)?

Functions like:

```
[nsstring integerValue],
[nsstring intValue]
```

seems to be 32bit limited (max value:2147483647).

Any Hints?

Data model with 64bit integer properties compiles fine so it means iPhone supports such a numbers for a god sake.
It must be some simple conversion method. It is so popular in http connection based devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried `longLongValue` ?

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[nsstring longLongValue]]; This is what I needed to store it as an object. Thank You. I was simply scared of this long long type ;-) Why not just long once?

Answer (score -1):

if they have a fixed length, you could cut them on each 9th number, make the intvalue of the cutted parts and add the values with the 10^9-factor. surely not the most elegant way, but it should work

Comment: Thanks - but it must be simple. I use it very often in constructing queries. Anyway - it is too basic thing to go so deep down to the forest ;-)